# Decrypt an encrypted SQLite DB in .Net

Tags: .net, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted SQLite DB (in .Net). According to Zetetic's documentation (https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/) one can use `sqlcipher_export` for this purpose, like so:

```
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}", fullDbPath));
        connection.Open();

        var key = //get it from somewhere
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT quote($password);";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$password", key);
        var quotedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.CommandText = $"PRAGMA key = {quotedPassword}; ATTACH DATABASE 'plaintext.db' AS plaintext KEY '';SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext');DETACH DATABASE plaintext";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, this throws an exception `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'table "__EFMigrationsHistory" already exists'.'`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my tests the code worked as expected and what it did, it `EXPORTED` the encrypted database to a new database file called `plaintext.db`.

Since you did not provide a full path for the `plaintext.db` file I'm not sure where it was generated, however if you were to provide a full filepath in the attach statement e.g: `ATTACH DATABASE 'C:\Users\John\Data\plaintext.db' AS plaintext KEY '';` a file `plaintext.db` would be created in that folder and it would contain the unencrypted data from the original database.

As for the exception that you were receiving, it must have been because the export code was called multiple times, the database with its tables was already created and now the subsequent export calls were trying to create tables that already existed which failed.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, I had previously tried to pass the full path to the plaintext db file to the command and got an error, I probably bungled something up, and assumed sqlcipher would just use the same folder as the input db.